# How do I wait until the user has finished writing down in a text input to call a function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm designing a web site and I would like to be able to call a function 1 second after the last user input. I tried using onKeyUp, but it waited 1 second after the first keystroke.

Does anyone know how would this be possible?

Comment: You can use an [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onchange.asp) event which occurs when the user leaves the field and moves to the next field in the form. You can then add your wait code in there and fire that 1 second after the field changes.

Comment: There are no straight, 100% ways to do it. The simplest is to use the blur event of the input. (other ways might be to wait X seconds **after** the user finished typing).

Comment: I would go with the [onblur](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_onblur.asp) event that occurs when an object loses focus. So it makes sure as soon as the user leaves the field that means he/she is done inputting their info.

Comment: Interesting question - is there any particular reason as to why you want to do that?

Comment: onchange() does not occur when the user leaves the field, that would be onblur(). From the link you provided 'The onchange event occurs when the content of a field changes.'

Comment: Yes, but the field does not register a change at each key-stroke.  If you press the enter key or, more commonly, the field loses focus then the change is picked up and the event fired.

Comment: Basically, when the user has finished typing in a text box, he is presented with a new one. Since the text box was the last one, I couldn't use onBlur() since I would have had to wait until the focus was on another box.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Another similar approach, without globals:

```
var typewatch = function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    }  
}();
```

...

```
<input type="text" onKeyUp="typewatch(function(){alert('Time elapsed!');}, 1000 );" />
```

You can this snippet [here](http://jsbin.com/ugafe/edit).

Comment: a+ ! +10 for doing it without globals  -1 for using obtrusive javascript. I'd rec. using this code and then calling this inside a keyup function, instead of the onclick attached to element.

Comment: This function does not work anymore

Answer (score 20):

You can use a `keyDown` (or `keyUp`) event that sets a function to run in 1 second and if the user types another key within that second, you can clear the timeout and set a new one.

E.g.

```
var t;    

function keyDown()
{
  if ( t )
  {
    clearTimeout( t );
    t = setTimeout( myCallback, 1000 );
  }
  else
  {
    t = setTimeout( myCallback, 1000 );
  }
}

function myCallback()
{
   alert("It's been 1 second since you typed something");
}
```

Comment: The below answer that doesn't use globals is a far superior approach.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found a way to do it. I call a function on each onkeyup() which increment a counter and then wait 1 second. After the 1 second elapsed, it decrement the counter and check if it's equal to 0.

```
var keystrokes = 0;
function askAgain()
{
    ++keystrokes;
    setTimeout(reveal, 1000);
}

function reveal()
{
    --keystrokes;

    if (keystrokes == 0)
        alert("Watch out, there is a snake!");
}
```

Comment: Heh, that's nice. If someone is a really fast typer they might have to wait a few seconds to see the message though :-)

Comment: @DanF I'm not really sure about it but I'd say that even if you are a really fast typer you'd wait just one second, because when you hit the last key, you will set the timeout that will make the keystrokes = 0 :-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Get the input box
let input = document.getElementById('my-input');

// Init a timeout variable to be used below
let timeout = null;

// Listen for keystroke events
input.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    // Clear the timeout if it has already been set.
    // This will prevent the previous task from executing
    // if it has been less than <MILLISECONDS>
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    // Make a new timeout set to go off in 1000ms (1 second)
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Input Value:', input.value);
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<!-- a simple input box -->
<input type="text" id="my-input" />
```

Credits to:
[Wait for User to Stop Typing, in JavaScript](https://schier.co/blog/wait-for-user-to-stop-typing-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your html input and toss that first line into your existing functions so you're not having to recode anything you have. It will not affect any old code-calling functions either, since if `onkeypress` is not set then `mykeypress` will always be < 1.

```
var mykeypress=0;
var mysleep=1000; //set this higher if your users are slow typers
function mytest(id,text) {
   mykeypress--; if(mykeypress > 0) { return; }
   //anything you want when user stops typing here
   alert("Keypress count at "+mykeypress+" ready to continue 
id is "+id+" arguement is "+text);
}

input type="text" name="blah" id="55" onkeypress="mykeypress++"
onkeyup="myid=this.id;setTimeout(function (){mytest(myid,'a test')},mysleep)"
REVERT to old way seamlessly:
input type="text" name="blah" id="55" onkeyup="mytest(this.id,'a test')"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some simple [plugin](https://github.com/AdamPietrasiak/Bid) I've made that does exacly that. It requires much less code than some proposed solutions and it's very light (~0,6kb)

First you create `Bid` object than can be `bumped` anytime. Every *bump* will delay firing *Bid* callback for next given ammount of time.

```
var searchBid = new Bid(function(inputValue){
    //your action when user will stop writing for 200ms. 
    yourSpecialAction(inputValue);
}, 200); //we set delay time of every bump to 200ms
```

When `Bid` object is ready, we need to `bump` it somehow. Let's attach bumping to `keyup` `event`.

```
$("input").keyup(function(){
    searchBid.bump( $(this).val() ); //parameters passed to bump will be accessable in Bid callback
});
```

---

**What happens here is:**

Everytime user presses key, bid is 'delayed' (bumped) for next 200ms. If 200ms will pass without beeing 'bumped' again, callback will be fired.

Also, you've got 2 additional functions for stopping bid (if user pressed esc or clicked outside input for example) and for finishing and firing callback immediately (for example when user press enter key):

```
searchBid.stop();
searchBid.finish(valueToPass);
```